# Seamless Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, remote-access

My employer provides us with the ability to work from home using the Citrix MetaFrame remote desktop software. For the most part, I have no complaints; however, **I was wondering if anyone knew if it is possible to do seamless remote desktop connections**?

By that, I mean is it possible to utilize this client (or another compatible client) to connect remotely to my machine at work and have the remote applications run side-by-side with my local applications as opposed to working within the confinement of a remote desktop window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real answer here is probably to just give you the right search terms so you can do some product comparison.  I think what you're talking about is "application virtualization," "application streaming," or "application sequencing" depending on the product.  Some options include XenApp, App-V, SVS, and ThinApp.

The only one I know anything about is [App-V](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/appv/default.mspx), but I think that's probably too much overhead for what you want to do.  Are there many other people that need to do the same thing, or is this just for you?

Edit: Just found [this](http://4sysops.com/archives/windows-server-2008-terminal-services-new-features-part-2/) in [another similar ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/8644/run-rdp-session-with-only-1-program).

Comment: There are a couple of other developers in the office that expressed interest in it, but there isn't really a department-wide demand for it.

Comment: Well, I know nothing about Citrix, but since you're using MetaFrame already it may be easier for you to implement XenApp - check this out:  http://www.citrix.com/english/ps2/products/product.asp?contentid=186

Comment: MetaFrame DOES do what you want. Your admin needs to publish each app seperately, as it stands now it looks like he's just published a full desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using Citrix, I would recommend you install and publish your frequently utilized applications so you can get to them from home via your ICA client. This may not work for everything, but should eliminate needing to run most of your applications from a remote desktop window which, I agree, is a pretty big pain.