# Run RDP Session with only 1 Program

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, terminal-server

I'm running a Windows Server 2008 box and would like to have users login via RDP, but only be able to run 1 program and if they close the program, to log off the session.  Is this possible?  The clients will be connecting from WinXP SP3 computers.

Thanks!
JFV

Comment: Here's a similar question from earlier today:

http://serverfault.com/questions/8583/seamless-remote-desktop-connection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new feature in Server 2008s terminal services called remoteapp that does what you're looking for I believe.

Description:
http://4sysops.com/archives/windows-server-2008-terminal-services-new-features-part-2/

MS Guide: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730673(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I checked it out and I was able to publish to the desktop.  I didn't know that Server 2008 had this Citrix-like setup.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set environment settings for every user on the Terminal server. 
Check in user environment settings to set startup program. 
It is built in feature. And if they close application, session will log off.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I'll look into that also!  Never can have too much information!

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done using the Remote Desktop Connection program that is installed on every computer Windows XP SP2 and higher.

When you start the program, click the "Options" button to display all options, and then click the "Programs" tab. Enter the local path of the program you wish to start (ie: c:\windows\notepad.exe).

Then save the connection as an RDP file and distribute it to your users.

Answer (score 0):

[2X ApplicationServer for Windows Terminal Services](http://www.2x.com/applicationserver/) does exactly what you are asking for and has a free version available with some limits.

I haven't used RemoteApp for 2008, so you might want to try that first, but I know the 2X software works and can also work with 2003.